# SQL Server - Get Database role membership from orphaned UserSID

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am currently using the following code within SQL Server 2005 to obtain data on orphaned user SID's, this works well but I really need to get information on role memberships for each orphaned userSID, is this possible and if so, how can I write a query for this?

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT name FROM sys.databases 
WHERE database_id > 4 

OPEN cur  

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @DBName SYSNAME 
DECLARE @Results TABLE (DBName SYSNAME, UserName SYSNAME, UserSID VARBINARY(MAX))  

FETCH NEXT FROM cur into @DBName  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
    SET @SQL = 'USE ' + @DBName + ';SELECT ''' + @DBName + ''' AS DBName, 
            UserName = name, UserSID = sid from sysusers 
            WHERE issqluser = 1 AND 
                (sid IS NOT NULL AND sid <> 0x0) AND 
                (LEN(sid) <= 16) AND SUSER_SNAME(sid) IS NULL'     

    INSERT INTO @Results 
    EXEC(@SQL)

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur into @DBName  
END  

CLOSE cur 
DEALLOCATE cur  

SELECT * FROM @Results
```

Thanks!

Thanks for the replies, I've created the below query based on the info given so far, this looks like it gives what I need?

```
select u.uid, u.name, u.sid, rm.role_principal_id as 'Role ID', dp1.name as 'Role'
from sys.sysusers u
left join sys.syslogins l on UPPER(u.sid) = UPPER(l.sid)
inner join sys.database_role_members rm on rm.member_principal_id = u.uid
left join sys.database_principals dp on dp.principal_id = rm.member_principal_id
left join sys.database_principals dp1 on dp1.principal_id = rm.role_principal_id 
where u.uid > 4 and u.issqlrole = 0
and issqluser = 1
and l.name is null
order by u.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It selects user membership.

```
select case when SUSER_SNAME( dp.sid ) is null then dp.name else SUSER_SNAME( dp.sid ) end 'dbUser',
dp2.name 'dbRole', dp.type_desc uDesc
from sys.database_principals dp left join sys.database_role_members dr 
on dr.member_principal_id = dp.principal_id
left join sys.database_principals dp2 on dr.role_principal_id = dp2.principal_id
where dp.type_desc <> 'DATABASE_ROLE'
and case when SUSER_SNAME( dp.sid ) is null then dp.name else SUSER_SNAME( dp.sid ) end
not in ('sys', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA', 'guest')
order by 1
```

I have noticed that your cursor selects orphaned SQL logins only. Do you need orphaned Windows logins? If yes, then check following query.

```
select u.name, *
from sys.sysusers u left join sys.syslogins l on UPPER(u.sid) = UPPER(l.sid)
where u.uid > 4 and u.issqlrole = 0 
and l.name is null
order by u.name
```

Comment: I think I'm almost there, I've built the relevant query which hopefully pulls the relevant ID's and roles across.